# Do something when contextMenu is showed

Tags: ios, list, view, contextmenu, swiftui

In the app I'm doing I show a chronometer running so you can know how much time you're using the app. But I would like to stop the chrono when the user enter in a contextMenu. 
I have not idea of how to do that!!
I need something like:

```
.contextMenu {
                    //chrono.stop <-- My wish :)
                    Button(action: {
                      self.addOcurrencia(a: tarea)
                    }) {
                      Text("Add".localized)
                      Image(systemName: "clock")
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                      tarea.tiempoAcumulado = Tarea.origenTiempo
                    }) {
                      Text("Reset".localized)
                      Image(systemName: "clear")
                    }
```

I appreciate any help you can give me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Notification when .contextMenu is dismissed (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714335/swiftui-notification-when-contextmenu-is-dismissed-ios)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to add an `onLongPressGesture` after the contextMenu:

```
  .contextMenu{
                                //chrono.stop <-- My wish :)

                                Button(action: {

                                }) {

                                  Image(systemName: "clock")
                                }

                                Button(action: {

                                }) {

                                  Image(systemName: "clear")
                                }
                   }
                 .onLongPressGesture( pressing: { (press) in
                       print(press)
                    // if press == false  {chrono.stop} <-- My wish :)
                 }, perform: {})
```