# SwiftUI: Notification when .contextMenu is dismissed (iOS)

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm using `.contextMenu` together with `.onDrag` on a view and this seems to be very tricky:

The background color changes to gray by setting `dragging` to true. This is triggered by `.onDrag` which already happens when opening the context menu (a bit early but ok). When I use the button to close the menu I can set `dragging` to false. When I use the drag, the `dragging` state is changed back to false when the `ItemProvider` is deinitialized. So far so good.

**The problem**

When I tap outside the context menu to dismiss it, I seem to have no way to set the `dragging` state back to false. Adding `.onDisappear` to the `Button` in the menu does not work.

What am I doing wrong here? Any way I can get either get notified when the context menu closes or have the state change of `dragging` happen when the drag actually begins (so that the background is not immediately gray when the context menu is opened)?

*Code below video.*

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dragging = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onDrag {
                    dragging = true
                    let provider =  ItemProvider(contentsOf: URL(string: "Test")!)!
                    provider.didEnd = {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            dragging = false
                        }
                    }
                    print("init ItemProvider")
                    return provider
                }
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("Close Menu") {
                        dragging = false
                    }
                }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(dragging ? Color.gray : Color.white)
    }
}

class ItemProvider: NSItemProvider {
    var didEnd: (() -> Void)?
    deinit {
        print("deinit ItemProvider")
        didEnd?()
    }
}
```

EDIT (Dec. 2022): It seems like the code works in iOS 16.2. I still haven't found a good solution to this for earlier iOS versions.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently experiencing the same issue right now with iOS 16

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention UIKit, `.contextMenu` is a `UIContextMenuInteraction`

You can add a `UIContextMenuInteraction` to a SwiftUI View and have access to `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` to identify when the menu is dismissed.

`SwiftUI View > ViewModifier > UIViewRepresentable > Coordinator/UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate`

```
struct CustomContextMenuView: View {
    @State var dragging = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onDrag {
                    dragging = true
                    let provider =  ItemProvider(contentsOf: URL(string: "Test")!)!
                    provider.didEnd = {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            dragging = false
                        }
                    }
                    print("init ItemProvider")
                    return provider
                }
            //Use custom context menu and add actions as [UIAction]
                .contextMenu(actions: [
                    UIAction(title: "Close Menu", handler: { a in
                        print("Close Menu action")
                        dragging = false
                    })
                ], willEnd:  {
                    //Called when the menu is dismissed
                    print("willEnd/onDismiss")
                    dragging = false
                }, willDisplay:  {
                    //Called when the menu appears
                    print("willDisplay/onAppear")
                    
                })
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(dragging ? Color.gray : Color.white)
        
    }
}
```

The Menu can be implemented by pasting the code below in a `.swift` file and using it like the sample above.

```
extension View {
    func contextMenu(actions: [UIAction], willEnd: (() -> Void)? = nil, willDisplay: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        modifier(ContextMenuViewModifier(actions: actions, willEnd: willEnd, willDisplay: willDisplay))
    }
}
struct ContextMenuViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let actions: [UIAction]
    let willEnd: (() -> Void)?
    let willDisplay: (() -> Void)?
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Interaction_UI(view: {content}, actions: actions, willEnd: willEnd, willDisplay: willDisplay)
            .fixedSize()
        
    }
}

struct Interaction_UI<Content2: View>: UIViewRepresentable{
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIView
    @ViewBuilder var view: Content2
    let actions: [UIAction]
    let willEnd: (() -> Void)?
    let willDisplay: (() -> Void)?
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        
        let v = UIHostingController(rootView: view).view!
        context.coordinator.contextMenu = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: context.coordinator)
        v.addInteraction(context.coordinator.contextMenu!)
        return v
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject,  UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate{
        var contextMenu: UIContextMenuInteraction!
        
        let parent: Interaction_UI
        
        init(parent: Interaction_UI) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
            UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: { [self]
                suggestedActions in
                
                return UIMenu(title: "", children: parent.actions)
            })
        }
        func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, willDisplayMenuFor configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
            print(#function)
            parent.willDisplay?()
        }
        func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, willEndFor configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
            print(#function)
            parent.willEnd?()
            
        }
    }
}
```